# change appearance of a child div when another child div is hovered over

Tags: html, css, css-selectors, hover, children

Im not sure if this is possible without using JS.

Basically Im trying to create an effect where you mouseover an image in a row and this image lights up and information about this is image displayed below.
While image rollover effect is straightforward, displaying the description underneath is hard to achieve.
I know I could do this as a tooltip, but the desired affect is to appear in page.

**See example**

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CsB1A.png

I believe the way to do this is to put each image into a seperate child div. 
Then on rollover of one of these child divs, have another information div change from "display:none" to "display:block".

The question is how do I make the hover selector on one child div affect a different child div?

```css
html, page {
     margin: 0px;
     padding: 0px;
     width: 100%;
     font-family: sans-serif;
    }
    
    
    .parent {
     border: 1px solid fuchsia;
     padding: 1%;
     height: 360px;
     width: 60%;
     min-width: 600px;
     max-width: 1200px;
     margin: 0 auto;
     display: flex;
     flex-wrap: wrap; 
     justify-content: space-between;
     }
    
    .child {
     display: block;
     background: white;
     height: 120px;
     width: 120px;
     border: 2px solid purple;
     border-radius: 80px;
     text-align: center;
     line-height: 120px;
     
    }
    
    
    .child:hover {
     background: cyan;
     border: 2px solid cyan;
    }
    
    .p1 {
     display: none; 
    }
    
    
    .p2 {
     display: none; 
    }
    
    
    .p3 {
     display: none; 
    }
    
    .p4 {
     display: none; 
    }
    
    
    .1:hover ~ .p1{
     display: block;
    }
    
    
    .2:hover ~ .p2{
     display: block; 
    }
    
    .3:hover ~ .p3{
     display: block; 
    }
    
    .4:hover ~ .p4{
     display: block; 
    }
    
    
    .childinfo {
     width: 100%;
     height: 200px;
     border: 2px solid cyan;
     margin-bottom: 0px;
     padding: 1%;
     text-align: center;
    }
```

```html
    <html>
    
    
    <body>
    
    <div class="parent">
    
    <div class="child 1">Child1</div>
    <div class="child 2">Child2</div>
    <div class="child 3">Child3</div>
    <div class="child 4">Child4</div>
    
    <div class="childinfo">
    <br><strong>Child Info Div</strong>
    
    
    <span class="p1">This is info about child 1 div</span>
    <span class="p2">This is info about child 2 div</span>
    <span class="p3">This is info about child 3 div</span>
    <span class="p4">This is info about child 4 div</span>
    
    </div>
    
    
    
    </div>
    
    </body>
    
    
    </html>
```

Comment: Use [General sibling combinator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/General_sibling_selectors)

Comment: Gave this a go - didn't work. Perhaps the sibling combinator doesn't work when used with the hover selector? 

Code updated in original post. let me know if i'm missing something.

Answer (score 1):

Managed to work it out.

Its not the cleanest CSS, with a lot of classes duplicating the same properties.

**Observations**

• General sibling combinator only worked provided the information that I wanted to display/hide was NOT in another child-div.
• Used a separator div (width: 100%) to separate the top children from the information shown on hover instead
• Used `<span>` to contain the information instead of divs

I realise, this doesn't look so flash but I'll be creating a section on my site with imagery and will link it here.

```css
body, html {
  padding: 0px;
  margin: 0px;
  font-family: sans-serif;
}

span {
 margin: 0 auto;
}

.parent {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: flex;
 flex-wrap: wrap; 
 justify-content: space-between;
  width: 80%;
  min-width: 816px;
  height: 300px;
  border: 2px solid fuchsia;
  text-align: center;
}

.divider {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8px !important;
  border: #cccccc;
}

.child1 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.child1:hover {
  background: cyan;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

.child1:hover ~ span.p1 {
  display: block;
}

.child2 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.child2:hover {
  background: cyan;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

.child2:hover ~ span.p2 {
  display: block;

}

.child3 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.child3:hover {
  background: cyan;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

.child3:hover ~ span.p3 {
  display: block;

}

.child4 {
  width: 200px;
  height: 200px;
  border: 2px solid purple;
  display: inline-block;
  border-radius: 120px;
  text-align: center;
  line-height: 200px;
}

.child4:hover {
  background: cyan;
  border: 2px solid cyan;
}

.child4:hover ~ span.p4 {
  display: block;
}


span {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">

<div class="child1">child 1</div>
<div class="child2">child 2</div>
<div class="child3">child 3</div>
<div class="child4">child 4</div>

<div class="divider"></div>
<!--/invisible divider ensures information and descriptions go to next line in the flex box-->

<span class="p1">Here is info about child 1</span>
<span class="p2">Here is info about child 2</span>
<span class="p3">Here is info about child 3</span>
<span class="p4">Here is info about child 4</span>

</div><!--/ parent div-->
```